# Unable to create nested date aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to create an ElasticSearch aggregation query which can generate sum or average of value in all my ingested documents.

The documents are of the format -

```
{
"weather":"cold",
"date_1":"2017/07/05",
"feedback":[
    {
    "date_2":"2017/08/07",
    "value":28,
    "comment":"not cold"
    },{
    "date_2":"2017/08/09",
    "value":48,
    "comment":"a bit chilly"
    },{
    "date_2":"2017/09/07",
    "value":18,
    "comment":"very cold"
    }, ...
    ]
}
```

I am able to create a sum aggregation of all "feedback.value" using "date_1" by using the following request -

```
GET _search
{
"query": {
        "query_string": {
                "query": "cold"
                 }
        },
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
        "temperature": {
                    "date_histogram":{
                                      "field" : "date_1",
                                      "interval" : "month"
                                      },
                      "aggs":{
                              "temperature_agg":{
                                                "terms": {
                                                        "field": "feedback.value"
                                                          }
                                                }
                              }

                    }
        }
}
```

However, I need to generate the same query across all documents aggregate based on "feedback.date_2". I am not sure if ElasticSearch can resolve such aggregation or how to approach it. Any guidance would be helpful

[EDIT]
Mapping file( I only define the nested items, ES identifes other fields on its own)

```
{
 "mappings": {
  "catalog_item": {
   "properties": {

      "feedback":{
          "type":"nested",
          "properties":{
              "date_2":{
                  "type":   "date",
                  "format":"YYYY-MM-DD"
              }, 

                "value": {
                "type": "float"
              },

                "comment": {
                "type": "text"
              }


          }
        }

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your mapping?

Comment: added the mapping file in an edit

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if that's what you were aiming for.

Comment: thanks, but I want to the sum/avg aggregation of "feedback.value" by "feedback.date_2". I was able to aggregate by "date_1" as shown in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make use of [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html).

Here's a working example:

**Sample Mapping:**

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "feedback": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Add Sample document:**

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
   "date_1": "2017/08/07",
  "feedback": [
    {
      "date_2": "2017/08/07",
      "value": 28,
      "comment": "not cold"
    },
    {
      "date_2": "2017/08/09",
      "value": 48,
      "comment": "a bit chilly"
    },
    {
      "date_2": "2017/09/07",
      "value": 18,
      "comment": "very cold"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Calculate both the sum and average based on date_2.**

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "temperature_aggregation": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "feedback"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "temperature": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "feedback.date_2",
            "interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "feedback.value"
              }
            },
             "avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "feedback.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to the sum/avg aggregation of "feedback.value" by "feedback.date_2". I was able to aggregate by "date_1" as shown in my post.

Comment: I get the following error - ```{
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "weather_data",
        "node" : "TzVL2gN8T5Se1VVZO8cjlw",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
          "reason" : "[nested] nested path [feedback] is not nested"
        }
      },...```

Comment: there are some responses as well, is this error because some of the "feedback" lists are empty?